# Bad return pointer c++

Tags: c++

I have a question for you... I have a function in c++ that returns a double pointer:

```
double * Calc_ToF_low::CalcToF(int16_t* señal, int fs){


    double ToF_est [4]={0,0,0,0};
    ToF_est[0]=time_est(result2,fs);
    ToF_est[1]=ToF_est[0];
    ToF_est[2]=ToF_est[0];
    ToF_est[3]=ToF_est[0];


    return(ToF_est);
```

And in main:

```
double *ToF_est;
ToF_est=ToFobject.CalcToF(señal,fs);
```

And when i do:

```
cout<<ToF_est[0]<<endl;
```

Not has the same value... why??

Thanks

Comment: Youre returning the address of a local variable. This is UB.

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a pointer to *automatic local variables*. It invokes **undefined behavior**. Once the function returns, `ToF_est` is no longer exist.
If you want to return a pointer then use dynamic allocation (`new`).

```
double *ToF_est = new double [4];
```